# Numpy value of dot product of each row and column stored in a new np array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm new to numpy and I want the value of the dot product of A[i] and B[i] stored in a new matrix. I have written code that does that, but it's using a nested loop and I know there has to be a more numpy way of doing it. Can anyone help please?

```
A = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
              [0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]])

B = np.transpose(A)

l = []

for i in A:
    for j in B:
        l.append(np.dot(i, j))
        
np.array(l).reshape(5,5)
```

Comment: `A @ A` is equal to that

Comment: I knew there would be something super simple, it's a basic operation after all. Perfect, thank you!

Comment: `np.dot` can work with 2d arrays.  Its docs should be clear on that.  `np.dot(X,Y)` does the sum-of-products on the last dimension of X and the 2nd to the last (first) of Y.  `np.matmul` has the docs for `@`.